# Where do the various international business card sizes come from?

Tags: print-design

According to the Wikipedia entry on "Business Cards", various countries employ several standard business card sizes. US/Canada use 3.5 x 2in, UK uses 85 x 55mm, ect.

Apparantly, the following countries use a 90 × 50mm card: **Argentina, Brazil, Czech Republic, Finland, Hungary, Israel, Kazakhstan, Poland, Romania, Russia, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Ukraine, Uzbekistan, Bulgaria, Latvia, Mexico and South Africa**

That's great to know, and I'm sure it's accurate, but can anyone tell me *what* standard sets the sizes for those countries?

I know that many derive from ISO 216, or ISO/IEC 7810 ID-1, but why does that remaining bucket list of countries (and a few others) use a completely arbitrarily defined size? (90 x 50mm)? I would like to find out exactly what that standard is, or if it's just some sort of random cultural deviation.

To be a little more specific, I'm looking for where *exactly* the 90x50mm size comes from, and if there is any kind of standard behind it. I'd like something beyond simply "it's relatively close to ISO 216, or ISO/IEC 7810 ID-1".

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 8):

**Where does 90x50 mm derive from?**

```
 #   mm              inches            aspect ratio
(1)  88.9 x 50.8     3.5 x 2           1.75
(2)  90 x 50         3.543 × 1.968     1.8
```

<sub>See [*full table*](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/629/what-are-the-dimensions-of-a-business-card/632#632).</sub>

1. USA & Canada (**Imperial & American system**)
2. Argentina, Brazil, Czech Republic, Finland, Hungary, Israel, Kazakhstan, Poland, Romania, Russia, Serbia, Slovakia, Slovenia, Ukraine, Uzbekistan, Bulgaria, Latvia, Mexico and South Africa (**metric system**)

So, 90 x 50 mm is metric version of the USA's & Canada's business card size. For evenness sake it probably is not 89 x 51 m.

Some Finnish forums referred to [SFS](http://www.sfs.fi/en/) recommendation, but I was unable to confirm this. It is clearly apparent, though, that the recommendation would be based on the North American customs.

---

**Where does 3.5 x 2 " derive from?**

I didn't find a straight answer to this, but stumbled into an interesting article about the [history of business cards](http://www.paperpenalia.com/cards.html), which state the dimensions are used at least starting form the Victorian era.

The "calling card" sizes were hierarchical and denoted the social status of the owner(s):

> The largest cards, measuring 3 3/8" x
>   2 1/2", were reserved for married
>   couples.
>
> A man could choose a card of either 3
>   3/8" x 1.5" or 3.5" x 2" dimensions.
>   Sizes then ranged down to that for a
>   married woman, a single woman, an
>   unarried daughter still living at
>   home, and a child, who had the
>   smallest card at 2.25" x 1 3/8".

So my own conclusion is the 3.5 x 2 " size is derived from the Victorian man's calling card size, and—again—probably is 3.5 x 2 " rather than 3 <sup>3</sup>/<sub>8</sub> x 1 ½ " for the evenness sake.

Comment: Neat! I knew the business card arose from the Victorian calling card, but never knew there was a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

What has become the UK standard size of business card, 85 x 55mm, seems to have been taken from the international standard credit card size, which is actually slightly smaller at 3 3/8" x 2 1/8" or c. 85 x 54mm. I assume the short dimension was "rounded up" for some reason.